# Spark, How to transform A B,C to (A, List(B,C))

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new in spark, and I want to implement PageRank algorithm .

For example I have a pagelink file the context is below:

```
A B,C 
B A,D
C A
D A,B
E A,B,D
```

And I want to transform it to :

```
(A,List(B,C))
(B,List(A,D))
(C,List(A))
(D,List(A,B))
(E,List(A,B,D))
```

I don't know how to do it with map function
Can someone teach me how to do it ,Please ?

Comment: what's wrong with a Map[String, List[String])?

Comment: @RamanMishra I figure it out ! thank you so much !!

Comment: I  use map(x => x.split(" ")).map(x => (x(0),x(1).split(",")))

Comment: You can post your own solution below as answer rather than leave as comment

Answer (score 2):

```
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._


val sourceData = spark
  .read
  .text("/path/example.txt")
  .toDF("value")

sourceData.printSchema()
//  root
//  |-- value: string (nullable = true)


val df1 = sourceData
  .select(
    split('value, " ").getItem(0).as("col1"),
    split('value, " ").getItem(1).as("col2"))

df1.printSchema()
//  root
//  |-- col1: string (nullable = true)
//  |-- col2: string (nullable = true)

df1.show(false)
//  +----+-----+
//  |col1|col2 |
//  +----+-----+
//  |A   |B,C  |
//  |B   |A,D  |
//  |C   |A    |
//  |D   |A,B  |
//  |E   |A,B,D|
//  +----+-----+

val df2 = df1.select('col1, split('col2, ",").as("col2"))
df2.printSchema
//  root
//  |-- col1: string (nullable = true)
//  |-- col2: array (nullable = true)
//  |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)

df2.show(false)
//  +----+---------+
//  |col1|col2     |
//  +----+---------+
//  |A   |[B, C]   |
//  |B   |[A, D]   |
//  |C   |[A]      |
//  |D   |[A, B]   |
//  |E   |[A, B, D]|
//  +----+---------+
```

V2: map

```
val r1 = spark.read.text("/path/example.txt")
val r2 = r1.map(x => x.getString(0).split(" ")).map(i => (i(0), i(1).split(",")))
```

Comment: thank you so much !!! I will try your data frame version !

Comment: The question seems to have key value input file, not a CSV

Comment: you can try also map version. V2: map

Comment: text file, not csv. rename csv to txt. 
we use spark.read.text(...)